# Adhoc polymorphism/function overloading not working in Swift when specifying a pattern in function signature

Tags: swift, polymorphism

I'm having some problems with polymorphism in Swift 2.2 and 2.3. I am working with `NSManagedObjects` and building views off of specific ones. I noticed my view builder wasn't calling the correct overloaded function based on the subclass of the model.

In a Playground I messed around with a few things and discovered the following:

```
import Foundation

class DataObject: NSObject {}
class X: DataObject {}
class Y: DataObject {}

class ViewBuilder {
    func viewForModel<S where S: DataObject>(model: S) {
        tmp(model)
    }

    func tmp(model: X) {
        print("X")
    }

    func tmp(model: Y) {
        print("Y")
    }

    func tmp(model: DataObject) {
        print("Base")
    }
}

ViewBuilder().viewForModel(X())
```

This prints out "Base" despite passing a type X. Am I missing something? Why is it calling the base class `tmp()` function instead of the one for the appropriate subclass?

Comment: Global functions in Swift are statically dispatched – therefore within a method with an generic parameter that inherits from `DataObject`, the only overload that could be called is the one that takes a `DataObject` input. Why not make the `tmp` method an instance method on `DataObject`, allowing the subclass to override it? Or define it with a protocol? Either approach would allow for polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, @Hamish, but that's actually how my NSManagedObject code is set up. The sample code that demos the same problems has the same result whether `tmp()` is global or a class method.

I unfortunately do not want to put `tmp()` in the NSMO as that would place too much view layer info in the model layer. Pretend I want my models to power completely different views in a UITableViewCell and a simple UIViewController.view. By providing an intermediate object in between the model and view layers that builds specific views for specific models, I was hoping I could re-use the model for any view.

Comment: @Hamish, I updated the example on SO to show that even as a method, it suffers the same problems as global functions. :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem of subclasses here is intriguing, but I'm wondering if you wouldn't be better off with something like this:

```
class ViewBuilder {
    func viewForModel(model: X) {
        print("X")
    }
    func viewForModel(model: Y) {
        print("Y")
    }
    func viewForModel(model: DataObject) {
        print("Base")
    }
}
```

This yields the desired results:

`ViewBuilder().viewForModel(X())` prints "X"

`ViewBuilder().viewForModel(Y())` prints "Y"

If you have `class Z: DataObject {}` that does not have a specific method:

`ViewBuilder().viewForModel(Z())` prints "Base"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `X` is first of all a `DataObject` and you have to cast to subclass like this:

```
func viewForModel<S where S: DataObject>(model: S) {
    model.dynamicType
    tmp(model as! X)
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the type will be (outside of this debugging example back in my Core Data app) at compile time, so I can't cast it. That's what I was hoping the pattern match would help with. All I know at `viewForModel()` is it's a base class and I'm trying to figure out how to get the compiler recognize its actual type and magically call the right method.

Comment: Of course, I could be asking too much from the compiler. I'm just wondering if there's a way to do that or not.